# How to mock the intrinsic JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to mock the call to JSON.parse being made in my react component's componentDidMount method and do not know how to achieve it.  My testing environment is jest, enzyme, jest-enzyme and jest-environment-enzyme.  The global object available to my tests is the window object from jsdom.window.document.defaultView.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to mock that?

Comment: *"Thanks in advance"*: You may have thought that on StackOverflow you can ask people to write code for you, but that is a misunderstanding. It is up to you to write the code, and when you have a *specific* problem you bump into while doing so, ask about that issue.

Comment: @SLaks It was more out of curiosity than out of necessity.  I have mocked the string to be parsed so I can just assert further along toEqual(JSON.parse(mockedString)).  Though it would be benefical to mock the return for equality testing in a custom matcher that I have written.

Comment: @trincot.  You may have thought that I had not spent any time in attempting to write the code to achieve what I wanted but that is a misunderstanding.  Yes I have omitted details on the code that I tried unsuccessfully but given the nature of the problem  I don’t think it is too much to ask, politely, for someone who knows the solution to kindly provide it while I continue to look at it. There is a difference between doing someone's coding for them to pasting in a line of code that they use when trying to accomplish the same or something similar under the conditions described.

Comment: The English in this question is really difficult to understand.

Comment: @user487779 given that your question doesn't contain any indication of the level of effort on your part, trincot's comment is reasonable.  Next time include what you've tried/researched.

Comment: @Amy trincot's comment would have been reasonable if it had not been condescending. 'Please can you provide further details on the steps you have taken.' would have been acceptable.

Comment: @user487779 maybe next time share what you tried/researched and no one will "condescend" toward you?  just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Assignment to global.JSON.parse does work.  An error in my code suggested otherwise.